# Test if a Property is not Null before Returning

Tags: c#

I have the following property

```
public MyType MyProperty {get;set;}
```

I want to change this property so that if the value is null, it'll populate the value first, and then return it... but *without* using a private member variable.

For instance, if I was doing this:

```
public MyType MyProperty 
{
    get
    {
        if (_myProperty != null)
            return _myProperty
        else
           _myProperty = XYZ;
            return _myProperty;
    }
    set
    {
        _myProperty = value;
    }
}
```

is this possible? Or do I need the member variable to get it done?

Comment: No. You can't have your cake and eat it too.

Comment: _without a [private] member variable_...  You lost me! Other than relying on some global/external feed of sorts, a property needs some variable(s) where to store its state.

Comment: @mjv: No, that is, not explicitly. With automatic properties (like in the first code snippet) the compiler generates the private field for you.

Comment: @Thomas: I realize this. The point I'm trying to make is whether _implicitly_ supplied by the compiler or _explicitly_ declared in the code, some variable(s) is (are) needed to implement any property which "directly" conveys a [internal] state.  The "_diretcly_" and "_internal_" parts of the statement edge for properties which merely provide some computation based on other properties/variables/states or which access global variables/services to fetch and/or store their "value".

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need a member variable and a full property declaration. Automatically implemented properties are *only* applicable if they're trivial wrappers around a field, with no logic involved. You can simplify your getter code slightly, btw:

```
get
{
    if (_myProperty == null)
    {
       _myProperty = XYZ;
    }
    return _myProperty;
}
```

(Note that none of this is thread-safe without extra locking, but I assume that's okay.)

By the way, you already *have* a private member variable if you're using automatically implemented properties - it's just that the compiler's generating it for you.

Comment: The funny thing is, a few weeks after posting the question I read your explanation of automatic properties in C# in Depth :-)
Thanks Jon, keep up the good work!

Comment: wish there would be something that could remove the if-check once it was set to a non-null value after first check :-) like dynamic code rewriting itself on condition making it permanent :)

Answer (score 15):

```
return _myProperty?? (_myProperty = XYZ);
```

Comment: Not very good. If `XYZ` is actually: `FarFarAwayServer.DoReallyLongCalculation()` you will suffer a lot. You probably meant: `return _myProperty ?? (_myProperty = XYZ);`. I don't like it, though.

Comment: Yes, i mean (_myProperty = XYZ). Thanks. But in case of FarFarAwayServer.DoReallyLongCalculation() it will suffer for other ways too, right?

Comment: Sure, but only once. Your original code would suffer all the time.

Answer (score 10):

The best thing you can do is to give it a value in the constructor. I know that this way you lose the "lazy loading", but you can't have auto properties and lazy loading at the same time.

Comment: Even if it's given a value in the constructor, it could (currently) still be set to null elsewhere. It *may* be more appropriate to make sure the value is set in the constructor, but that's really about the semantics of the property rather than the code used to implement it.

Comment: @Jon : Good point.  So make the setter never allow the property to be null :)

Comment: @galford13x: that would also deprive you of the ability to use auto properties, tho

Comment: @galford13x ... and never, ever, EVER, *EVER*, use the field directly. This is one of the reason I'd like to have the property braces introduce scope, so we could have "property-private fields".

Comment: @David: Ah yes, I lost track of the purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Your code:

```
public MyType MyProperty {get;set;}
```

refer to "[Automatic Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)", that are just "syntactic sugar", as you can check out [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/abhinaba/archive/2007/09/21/cool-new-c-syntactic-sugar.aspx).

> The compiler generates the field for
>   the property and also generates the
>   code in the get set to point to the
>   field.
>
> ```
> internal class ClassName
> {
>     // Fields
>     [CompilerGenerated]
>     private MyType <Property>k__BackingField;
>
>     // Properties
>     public MyType MyProperty
>     {
>         [CompilerGenerated]
>         get
>         {
>             return this.<Property>k__BackingField;
>         }
>         [CompilerGenerated]
>         set
>         {
>             this.<Property>k__BackingField = value;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

So, your code will **always** be backed by a compiler generated field.

Answer (score 2):

You need the member variable to get it done:

```
public class MyClass
{
    MyType _myProperty = null;

    public MyType MyProperty
    {    
        get
        {
            if(_myProperty == null)
                _myProperty = XYZ;

            return _myProperty;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The part whre I say that you need a private member variable because Auto Properties doesn't support what he wants to do.

Comment: @XpiritO: "No, you can't" is a valid answer to "Is it possible?". I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need a private variable to implement this because you have logic in your getter/setters.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. But you have to implement it yourself, not with auto properties. Your properties do not necessarily need to only work with member variables though that is the default.

Remember that properties are actually turned into Getter and Setter methods and you can do a lot of work within their scope. Though this practice is usually discouraged. Good practices states that property access ought to be quick and not block the client code for long perieds of time.

You could simply do this:

```
public MyType MyProperty 
{
    get
    {
        if (_myProperty != null)
            return _myProperty
        else
            return XYZ;
    }
    set
    {
        _myProperty = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to do any embellishment on the getting or setting behavior of a property, then you will lose the compiler-generated storage location, so you'll have to store the value somewhere yourself. A private member variable makes the most sense, most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

I propose to consider usage of [Lazy initialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd997286(v=vs.110).aspx). 
It will not help you to avoid member variable so sorry for this, but that code will help you to avoid memory reservation for member variable until your class will need that variable:

```
public class MyType
{
    public MyType()
    {
        XYZ();
    }

    public void XYZ()
    {
        //some kind of initialization
    }
}

public class TestType
{
    private Lazy<MyType> _myProperty;
    public MyType MyProperty
    {
        get { return _myProperty.Value; }//_myProperty will be null until some code will try to read it
    }

}
```

One more thing to point or actually to remind, you'll not be able to be absolutely without member variable. Because behind the curtains .Net compiler will create that member variable instead of you. It just will not notify you about this step. But as it was mentioned by others, if you look in generated MSIL, you'll see that member variable created for you.

Answer (score 0):

Only when you use a member variable.

Usually, I combine lazy loading with the [implementation of IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx), so that any variables that need to be cleaned up can be handled in the Dispose method.

Answer (score 0):

By "member variable" I assume you mean a variable defined within the property get.  Yes, you certainly don't need a locally defined variable.  The more common pattern, which saves a copule lines of code, is:

```
    if (_myProperty == null)
        _myProperty = XYZ;

    return _myProperty;
```

If by "member variable" you mean a backing field, then yes, you do need one.  Only the completely simple "pass through" field/property relationship can be implemented without explicitly creating a backing field.  (And even then, it's get's created by the compiler.)  To instantiate-if-null, you need to explicitly define it.

Answer (score 0):

**If** the property is required then some checking can make it bullet proof. I tend to use something like:

```
public MyType MyProperty 
{
  get
  {
    if (_myProperty == null)
        _myProperty == XYZ;
    return _myProperty;
  }
  set
  {
    if(value == null)
        throw InvalidArgumentException();
    _myProperty = value;
  }
}
```

Makes TDD simpler too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Public Class MyClass
{    
    Public MyType Alfa
    {
        If(this._Alfa == null) this.SetAlfa();
        return _Alfa;
    }

    private MyType _Alfa {get;set;}

    private void SetAlfa()
    {
        //Somenthing to valorize _Alfa
    }    
}
```